# Access app-id.appspot.com through CDN

Tags: google-app-engine, cdn

I'm located in china. So I can't acess my application which is deployed on google app engine directly. I need a content distribution network(CDN) like ClouldFlare, however it does not support the subdomain appspot.com any more. By the way, speedymirror is also invalid.

Are there any other alternatives, which can support appspot.com ?